# Set cassandra.yaml settings like seeds through a script

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-cli

What is the best way to set yaml settings? I am using docker containers and want to automate the process of setting cassandra.yaml settings like seeds, listen_address & rpc_address.

I have seen something like this in other yaml tools: <%= ENV['envsomething'] %>

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for information.

I was considering using https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml

But this guy did the trick: https://github.com/abh1nav/docker-cassandra

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the "best" way but when I set up a scripted cluster of cassandra servers on a few vagrant vms I used puppet to set the seed and so on in cassandra.yaml.

I did write some scripting than used puppetdb to keep track of the addresses of the hosts but this wasn't terrifically successful.  The trouble was the node that came up first only had itself in the list of seeds and so tended to make a cluster on it's own.  Then the rest would come up as a seperate cluster.  So I had to take down the solo node, clear it out and restart it with correct config

If I did it now I would set the addresses as static ip, then use them to fill in the templates for the cassandra.yaml files on all the nodes.  Then hopefully the nodes would come up with the right idea about the other cluster members.

I don't have any experience with Docker but they do say the way to use puppet+Docker is to use puppet on the Docker container before starting it up

Please note that you need a lot of memory to make this work.  I had a machine with 16GB and that was a bit dubious.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Cassandra in Docker use this as an example: https://github.com/tobert/cassandra-docker You can override cluster name/seeds when launching so whatever config management tool you use for deploying your containers could do something similar.